# Mac OS X: What's wrong with my keyboard?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, keyboard

In OS X when I press <kbd>/</kbd> it comes out as `-` and when I press <kbd>;</kbd> it comes out as `ö`.

Comment: Sounds like you have your locale set wrong. Should be somewhere in the system settings.

Comment: Looks like a german keyboard layout.

Comment: Also, Finnish, Icelandic, Swedish.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the input source is in the wrong language then you ca change it by

1) In the menu bar there might be a flag denoting the language - click on it and it will give a list of ative input sources.

2) Otherwise open System Preferences and go to Language&Text->Input Sources and choose your language